# Setting the default value for app's cellular data access to "off"

Tags: ios, cellular-network

I'm completing an app whicH displays publicly accessible data. Though each discrete data set isn't huge (roughly A 30kb download) there are a lot of them, so if the user digs deep into data, they could easily burn up maybe 10mb in a few minutes, and so is better suited to WiFi. I've coded a check when the app detects that the user is on cellular data and warns them, but I'm wondering if the default value for the app's ability to use cellular data can be turned off upon app install? I recall seeing this behavior in some streaming apps I use.
Thanks